# XmlPullParser:PI must not start with xml, but only on Android 2.3.3 downwards

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I get no error on Android 3.0+, but only on Android 2.2, 2.3.3 when I try to parse a small XML file via `XmlPullParser`, the app breaks with an error:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: PI must not start with xml 
(position:unknown @1:5 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40568770)
```

**What is PI mentioned in the error???**

I found out that this may cause the first line of XML file (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`), but I did not find the reason why this is happening on lower Android versions.

If this is the cause of error (first line of XML file), how can I fix this?

**Should I:**
a) ask the admin of web server to change XML? If yes, what he should change in XML?
b) substring `InputStream` using `BufferedReader`?

Somehow I think that **the 2nd approach will cause extra delays** on weak Android phones.

**EDIT**

I pulled XML content from debugger and saw that the first like is ending with `\r\n`, then the next characters starts. Does this say anything to you?

And this is how XML file look like. It's a small one and there is no visual reason why app is crashing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<song>
  <artist>Pink Floyd</artist>
  <title>Shine On You Crazy Diamond</title>
  <picture>http://www.xxyz.com/images/image.jpg</picture>
  <time>Fri, 23 Nov 2012 11:22:31 GMT</time>
</song>
```

This is how InputStream taken from this XML look like (starting chars only).

[image]

Please advise!!!

Comment: `I found out that this may cause the first line of XML file (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>)`
I tought you would get this error, if it's *not* on the first line or together with your XML in one line, If so then I would contact the Admin, if that did not work then try regex.´to get it the way it should be

Comment: @Ahmad What does it mean "... then try regex.´to get it the way it should be"???

Comment: Ok, first how does the document exactly look like? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Ahmad No I cannot. It's a secret location. I will copy XML here. A basic small file with one entry.

Comment: is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` the first line or is there something before it? E.g. a linebreak?

Comment: @Ahmad Not according to debugger. The first element of array pulled from `InputStream` is `<`. I will attach image taken from debugger now.

Comment: hmm... that's indeed strange. Sorry then I don't know how to fix that :/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with a data file I have been using on an App. Was having this exception on android 2.3.* and the problem was the UTF-8 BOM, so the easier solution I found, on Windows, was use the Notepad++ tool, and that let you convert the file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the xml parser source it seems that the issue occurs due to a byte order marker on the beginning of the response, in my case '77u/' (in base64).
If you don't convert the stream to String but parse it directly the parser correctly throws this away.

For example instead of

```
String xml = new String(xmlData, "UTF-8");
KXmlParser parser = new KXmlParser();
parser.setInput(new StringReader(xml));
```

use

```
KXmlParser parser = new KXmlParser();
parser.setInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData), null);
```

As an alternative you could also substring until the first '<'

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem.

For me I replaced all `'\n'` with space `' '` and then it worked.

**PS:**

@Ahmad said, a blank line before  could also cause this problem, better to check the first character '<' of a xml string.